# Mongoose validation failed, without giving the field-name with the issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I try to save my "Rating" schema, it gives the error

```
error:  ValidationError: Rating validation failed
```

without giving the field name with the problem, neither the kind of issue (if it's about a casting, a null or missing value, or something else..)

In my schema I don't have any field "required", neither "index:true"... I just specify the types in this way:

```
 {
  ex_string_field  :   {type:String},
  ex_number_field  :   {type:Number}, 
  ex_array_field   :   [    
                        {
                          sub_field_string : {type:String}
                         }
                       ],
  ex_object_field  :   {
                        sub_field_string : {type:String}
                       }
  }
```

How can I find which is the field rising the error? I have many fields. Actually, without any required field, it should be pretty easy to validate an object. I guessed that if a field is not compliant, it's just ignored....

This is my system:

```
"mongoose": "^4.11.12",
"node"    : "v8.1.3",
"npm"     : "5.3.0"
```

And this is the full error stack track:

```
2017-12-5 - error:  ValidationError: Rating validation failed
    at ValidationError (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:28:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1658:32)
    at model.Document.$set (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:760:10)
    at model._handleIndex (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:590:14)
    at model.Document.$set (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:550:24)
    at model._handleIndex (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:574:12)
    at model.Document.$set (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:550:24)
    at model.Document (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:77:12)
    at model.Model (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:55:12)
    at new model (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3885:13)
    at /Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/server/routes/admin/admin-utils.js:370:13
    at _fulfilled (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
```

================== UPDATE ====================

After some testing, I ended up that the error is the complex field 'main_info'. In the specific, 2 types were swapped (a number as String, and a String as Number). They were defined as follow:

```
this.schema = new Schema({
  main_info :
   {
        rea :                       {type:String},
        name :                      {type:Number},
    }
 });
```

This is an example of passed data that rise the Validation Error:

```
main_info :
{
  "rea": 649087,
  "name": "NUTIS S.R.L."
}
```

Anyway I think that it's crazy manual parse the whole data to find which is the problem. Does Mongoose really not provide any further info about the validation fail?

Comment: You also have a error:  ValidationError: Company validation failed

Comment: sorry, my mistake in copy-paste. I've corrected it now

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying to insert ?

Comment: added. Anyway it's not possible to do this by hand :(

Comment: found which was the problem, I've updated my question. Anyway I don't know how to find it through the mongoose error, instead of looking for it manually.

Comment: ```at /Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/server/routes/admin/admin-utils.js:370:13```

Comment: ```at /Volumes/HD Daniele/Sites/cashinvoice/server/server/routes/admin/admin-utils.js:370:13```this line is causing an error. just past admin-utils.js code for more insight

Comment: It’s the new Rating(obj).save() that rises the error